# Get object based on start date with only the day date

Tags: python, date, object

I am trying to retrieve an object with only the day number, where day is a variable containing the day number e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4... 29, 30, 31. (I'm using python with the django web framework). So I have a start_date field which is a DateField, and I want to search to get objects with a particular day in the start_date.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
holiday_object = Holiday.objects.get(start_date.day=day)
```

I can't do start_date.day=day...

> SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

How do I do this?

Comment: Are you using django?

Comment: Yes I am I'll add that above

Comment: what error it is throwing? & what is day here?

Comment: day is an integer. It is the day part of the date for a date in the current month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I had the current month and the current year, I formatted my date as follows and then did the search

```
format_date = "{0}-{1}-{2}".format(self.year, self.month, day)
holiday_object = Holiday.objects.get(start_date=format_date)
```

This worked just fine!

Answer (score 1):

`start_date.day` is a Python expression that tries to lookup the attribute `day` on whatever object is bound to name `start_date`. As the error message tells you, you cannot use an expression as a keyword for a function call.

The correct syntax here would be `Holiday.objects.get(start_date__day=day)` - but beware, this will return all `Holiday` records whose `start_date` day does match, *whatever the year and month*. Note sure this is what you want...

Answer (score 0):

try this way..

```
Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now())
```